# How i Protect Folder with htaccess Kohana 3.2 App

Tags: .htaccess, kohana

Hello guys I need a HELP, I use in my application Kohana, and created a root folder called media to imgs, css, and js so I want to protect access it without the url for the site to function, is doing that?

**Example:**

- app folder
- system folder
- modules folder
- media **new folder** (i need protect this folder)
- index.php

My File .htaccess in root is:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>


# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]



# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d




# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about [hotlinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlink).

Return 403 Forbidden with .htaccess (assuming example.com is your domain name):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|js|css)$ - [F]
```

Here is a special generator: http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/

Comment: i need protect only folder media, how do I do?

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^media/(.*) - [F]`

Comment: worked ok not access the folder, but for me to access the css files?

Comment: You should change `example\.com` with your domain.